# Custom launcher icon opens a second generic icon

Tags: launcher, icons, window, .desktop

I wrote a script in python to make my volume louder using pactl. I made a .desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Super Volume
Icon=/home/tyler/SuperVolume/icon.ico
Exec=/home/tyler/SuperVolume/SuperVolume.py
```

All was well

[image: Launcher item with icon]
but then i noticed that it was not adding the white arrow to my icon but opening a generic icon and putting the arrow on that

[image: The dreaded generic icon]

So if anyone could tell me how to change this I would really appreciate it I googled a lot before asking here but maybe wasn't using the right keywords, not sure.

Comment: Hi Sudo, I must have missed your question, would have answered earlier for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### About Tkinter windows

The window in your image is a *Tkinter* window. Tkinter windows by default do not match the launcher icon *unless* you specifically set the launcher (`.desktop` file) to match the window's `WM_CLASS`. Further below is explained how to do that.

***however***

If you do not define a specific `WM_CLASS` in your `python`/`Tkinter` code, all `Tkinter` windows have the same `WM_CLASS`. You can see that if you run

```
xprop WM_CLASS
```

in a terminal, press <kbd>Return</kbd>, and subsequently click on the `Tkinter` window. This will show:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "tk", "Tk"
```

This means that if you possibly have multiple `Tkinter` applications, they would all appear under the same icon in the launcher. This would be a *generic* one unless you edit your `.desktop` file.

#### How to set a distintive WM_CLASS in python/Tkinter

You can define the `WM_CLASS` by setting it like below:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *

# set the WM_CLASS
win = Tk(className="applicationname")
# set the window title
win.wm_title("Test 123")
win.mainloop()
```

[image]

#### Add the WM_CLASS to your .desktop file

Add the following line to your `.desktop` file:

```
StartupWMClass=applicationname
```

where `applicationname` is the name you set in the `python`/`Tkinter` code.

Comment: @SudoRmRf glad it works :)